# How to extract list of unique email addresses from a file in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to extract a list of unique email addresses from a .txt file (https://www.py4e.com/code3/mbox.txt) that contains multiple email messages. I am able to pull a list of email addresses by narrowing my search to the 'From:' and 'To:' lines with the below program:

```
import re
in_file = open('dummy_text_file.txt')
for line in in_file:
if re.findall('^From:.+@([^\.]*)\.', line):
    countFromEmail = countFromEmail + 1
    print(line)
if re.findall('^To:.+@([^\.]*)\.', line):
    print(line)
```

However, this does not provide me with a unique list as various of the email addresses repeat themselves. Furthermore, what does end up being printed, looks like the below:

To: java-user@lucene.apache.org

From: Adrien Grand < jpountz@gmail.com >

I am looking to only list the actual email address without the 'to', 'from', or the angle brackets (<>).

I'm not well versed with Python but my original way of approaching this was to extract the pure email addresses, and maybe store those somewhere and create a for loop to add them to a list.

Any help or pointers in the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: To the best of my knowledge there is no built-in method for removing duplicates. I would recommend checking out the following links to a solution to that specific problem: https://www.peterbe.com/plog/uniqifiers-benchmark  |   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-whilst-preserving-order

Answer (score 0):

For getting a list of unique emails I would check out the following two articles:

https://www.peterbe.com/plog/uniqifiers-benchmark

[How do you remove duplicates from a list whilst preserving order?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/480214/how-do-you-remove-duplicates-from-a-list-whilst-preserving-order)

For parsing `Adrien Grand < jpountz@gmail.com >` into a different format, the following link should contain all the information you need.

https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/email.parser.html#module-email.parser

Unfortunately, I don't the time to write you up an example but I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way to do it is `set()`.

Sets contain only unique values.

```
array = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 5]
unique_array= set(array)
print(unique_array)  # {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import re
in_file = open('mbox.txt')
countFromEmail = 0
unique_emails = set() #using a set to maintain an unique list
for line in in_file:
    if re.findall('^From:.+@([^\.]*)\.', line):
        countFromEmail += 1
        line = line.replace("From:","") #replacing the string
        line = line.strip() # then trimming the white spaces
        unique_emails.add(line) #adding to the set
    if re.findall('^To:.+@([^\.]*)\.', line):
        line = line.replace("To:","") #replacing the string
        line = line.strip() #then trimming the white spaces
        unique_emails.add(line) #adding to the set
for email in unique_emails:
    print email
```

> You can achieve this result in many different ways. Using a collection of a set can be one of them. As the elements inside the set are unique (any duplicate elements are discarded by default upon insertion).

[Read more here for the unordered collection of unique elements (SET) in python](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html)

I have edited and commented your code for you. Hope this helps. Cheers! :)

-Mehedi H.